# Good C Coding practice/etiquette for integrity checks

Tags: c, design-patterns, error-handling

Two part question;

I'm Coming from a high level Language, so this is a question about form not function;

I've written an isnumeric() function that takes a char[] and returns 1 if the string is a number taking advantage of the isdigit() function in ctype. Similar functions are  builtin to other languages and I have always used something like that to integrity check  the data before converting it to a numeric type. Mostly because some languages conversion functions fail  badly if you try to convert a non-number string to an integer.

But it seems like a kludge having to do all that looping to compensate for the lack of strings in C, which poses the first part of the question;

Is it acceptable practice in C to trap for a 0 return from atoi() in lieu of doing an integrity check on the data before calling atoi()? The way atoi() (and other ascii to xx functions) works seems to lend itself well to eliminating the integrity check altogether. It would certainly seem more efficient to just skip the check.

The second part of the question is;
Is there a C function or common library function for a numeric integrity check 
on a string? (by string, I of course mean char[])

Comment: `I've witten an isnumeric() function.` identifiers that start with `is` are reserved. Good coding practice would imply that you avoid using them.

Comment: Off-topic for multiple reasons.

Comment: Do you care if the string of digits can be represented by an int? Or do you just want to know if the string contains only decimal digits?

Comment: To close voters: 2nd question "Is there a C function or common library function for a numeric integrity check on a string?" is certainly not opinion base:  `strtol() strtod(), strtoull() .... (8+  functions)`

Comment: @jxh I'm looking for a way to determine if the string contains ONLY base 10 digits or a decimal or a comma. So if the string is 100,000.01 I want a positive return from func.  Any other ascii characters anywhere in the string would result in a negative return value.

Comment: Then `atoi` would not help.

Comment: @JackGalt You could use regular expressions as well. POSIX describes the standard C regex library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it acceptable practice in C to trap for a 0 return from atoi() in lieu of doing an integrity check on the data before calling atoi()?

Never ever trap on error unless the error indicates a programming error that can't happen if there isn't a bug in the code. Always return some sort of error result in case of an error. Look at the OpenBSD [`strtonum`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man3/strtonum.3) function for how you could design such an interface.

> The second part of the question is; Is there a C function or common library function for a numeric integrity check on a string? (by string, I of course mean char[])

Never use `atoi` unless you are writing a program without error checking as `atoi` doesn't do any error checking. The [`strtol`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtol.html) family of functions allow you to check for errors. Here is a simply example of how you could use them:

```
int check_is_number(const char *buf)
{
    const char *endptr;
    int errsave = errno, errval;
    long result;

    errno = 0;
    result = strtol(buf, &endptr, 0);
    errval = errno;
    errno = errsave;

    if (errval != 0)
        return 0; /* an error occured */

    if (buf[0] == '\0' || *endptr != '\0')
        return 0; /* not a number */

    return 1;
}
```

See the manual page linked before for how the third argument to `strtol` (base) affects what it does.

`errno` is set to `ERANGE` if the value is out of range for the desired type (i.e. `long`). In this case, the return value is `LONG_MAX` or `LONG_MIN`.

Comment: I think, it is worth mentioning that this function also returns true on `0xabc` and false on `0123456789` (and why this is). Maybe `10` as third argument to `strtol()` better meets the OPs expectations.

Comment: @Ctx I expect OP to read the manual page I linked to. But let me add a comment on this matter.

Comment: Nice preservation of `errno`, a subtle useful code addition. (IMO: should also restore before `if (errno != 0) return 0;`)

Comment: @FUZxxl - Thanks for the excellent example! I've been playing with strtol() and strtof().  I'm trying to figure a clean way to check for either numeric type in a single call without having to try this-if fail-try that, which is why I resorted to looping through each element and using '!isdigit(char[i]) && char[i] != '.''

Comment: @JackGalt That method won't catch overlow though. My code has one little problem, give me a second to apply chux's fix.

Answer (score 1):

If the conversion method returns an error indication (as distinct from going bananas if an error occurs, or not providing a definitive means to check if an error has occurred) then there is actually no need to check if a string is numeric before trying to convert it.

With that in mind, using `atoi()` is not a particularly good function to use if you need to check for errors on conversion.  Zero will be returned for zero input, as well as an error, and there is no way to check on why.    A better function to use is (assuming you want to read an integral value) is `strtol()`.  Although `strtol()` returns zero on integer, it also returns information that can be used to check for failure.   For example;

```
long x; 
char *end;

x = strtol(your_string, &end, 10);
if (end == your_string)
{
     /*  nothing was read due to invalid character or the first 
         character marked the end of string */
}
else if (*end != '\0`)
{
    /*  an integral value was read, but there is following non-numeric data  */
}
```

Second, there are alternatives to using `strtol()`, albeit involving more overhead.   The return values from `sscanf()` (and, in fact, all functions in the `scanf()` family) can be checked for error conditions.

There is no standard function for checking if a string is numeric, but it can be easily rolled using the above.

```
int IsNumeric(char *your_string)
{
     /*  This has undefined behaviour if your_string is not a C-style string
           It also deems that a string like "123AB" is non-numeric
     */
     long x; 
     char *end;

     x = strtol(your_string, &end, 10);
     return !(end == your_string || *end != '\0`);
}
```

No (explicit) loops in any of the above options.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it acceptable practice in C to trap for a 0 return from atoi() in lieu of doing an integrity check on the data before calling atoi()?

No. [@FUZxxl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35523503/2410359) well answers that.

> Is there a C function or common library function for a numeric integrity check on a string?

In C, the conversion of a string to a number and the check to see if the conversion is valid is usually done together.  The function used depends on the type of number sought.  "1.23" would make sense for a floating point type, but not an integer.

```
// No error handle functions
int atoi(const char *nptr);
long atol(const char *nptr);
long long atoll(const char *nptr);
double atof(const char *nptr);

// Some error detection functions
if (sscanf(buffer, "%d", &some_int) == 1) ...
if (sscanf(buffer, "%lf", &some_double) == 1) ...

// Robust methods use
long               strtol(   const char *nptr, char ** endptr, int base);
long long          strtoll(  const char *nptr, char ** endptr, int base);
unsigned long      strtoul(  const char *nptr, char ** endptr, int base);
unsigned long long strtoull( const char *nptr, char ** endptr, int base);
intmax_t           strtoimax(const char *nptr, char ** endptr, int base);
uintmax_t          strtoumax(const char *nptr, char ** endptr, int base);
float              strtof(   const char *nptr, char ** endptr);
double             strtod(   const char *nptr, char ** endptr);
long double        strtold(  const char *nptr, char ** endptr);
```

These robust methods use `char ** endptr` to store the string location where scanning stopped.  If *no* numeric data was found, then `*endptr == nptr`.  So a common test could is

```
char *endptr;
y = strto...(buffer, ..., &endptr);
if (buffer == endptr) puts("No conversion");
if (*endptr != '\0') puts("Extra text");
```

If the *range* was exceed these functions all set the global variable `errno = ERANGE;` and return a minimum or maximum value for the type.

```
errno = 0;
double y = strtod("1.23e10000000", &endptr);
if (errno == ERANGE) puts("Range exceeded");
```

The integer functions allow a radix selection from base 2 to 36.  If `0` is used, the leading part of the string `"0x"`, `"0X"`, `"0"`, `other` --> base 16, 16, 8, 10.

```
long y = strtol(buffer, &endptr, 10);
```

Read the specification or help page for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need a function to check whether a string is numeric. You will most likely need to convert the string to a number so just do that. Then check if the convertion is successful.

```
long number;
char *end;
number = strtol(string, &end, 10);
if ((*string == '\0') || (*end != '\0'))
{
    // empty string or invalid number
}
```

the second argument of `strtol` is used to indicate where the parsing ended (the first non-numeric character). That character will be `\0` if we've reached the end of the string. If you want to permit other characters after the number (like ), you can use `switch` to check for it.

`strtol` works with `long` integers. If you need some other type, you should consult the man page: `man 3 strtol`. For floating-point numbers you can use `strtod`.

Don't trap if the program logic permits that the string is not numeric (e.g. if it comes from the user or a file).

Answer (score 0):

OP later [commneted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35523358/good-c-coding-practice-etiquette-for-integrity-checks/35525255#comment58742818_35523358):

> I'm looking for a way to determine if the string contains ONLY base 10 digits or a decimal or a comma. So if the string is 100,000.01 I want a positive return from func. Any other ascii characters anywhere in the string would result in a negative return value.

If is all your interest, use;

```
if (buffer[strspn(buffer, "0123456789.,")] == '\0') return 0; // Success
else return -1; // Failure
```